Python Beautiful Soup not loading table values
I am unsure how to extra the 'Settle' column for each state (New South Wales, Victoria, Queensland, South Australia) from this website:
https://www.asxenergy.com.au/futures_au
It seems the numerical data isn't showing.
My starting code is:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://www.asxenergy.com.au/futures_au"
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.get_text())



This is probably because you're using urlopen() which cannot process javascript.

You can use Selenium WebDriver to handle that JavaScript. Then, you have to use CSS or XPath selectors for the Settle column and you can use a for-loop to iterate through the elements.

The data is loaded from here https://www.asxenergy.com.au/futures_au/dataset

As stated, the data comes from asxenergy.com.au/futures_au/dataset
Use pandas to get the <table> tags. It's not ideally structured, so need a bit of processing here.
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.asxenergy.com.au/futures_au/dataset'
dfs = pd.read_html(url)

states = dfs[0].iloc[0].to_list()
table_names = list(dfs[1].columns[0])
data_dfs = dfs[2:]
    
output = {}
for count, state in enumerate(states):
    start_idx = count * 6
    end_idx = start_idx + 6
    set_idx = list(range(start_idx, end_idx))
    
    temp_table_names = [table_names[i] for i in set_idx]
    temp_data_dfs = [data_dfs[i] for i in set_idx]

    data_dict = dict(zip(temp_table_names, temp_data_dfs))
    
    output[state] = data_dict

Output:
for state, tables in output.items():
    for table_name, df in tables.items():
        print(state, '-', table_name)
        print(df, '\n')


New South Wales - BMth
    BMth Bid Ask Last +/- Vol  Settle
0  Jul24   -   -    -   -   -  130.75
1  Aug24   -   -    -   -   -  117.74
2  Sep24   -   -    -   -   -   97.43
3  Oct24   -   -    -   -   -  110.00 

New South Wales - BQtr
   BQtr     Bid     Ask    Last +/-  Vol  Settle
0  Q324  113.50  115.50  115.50   -   40  115.50
1  Q424  109.50  110.00  110.00   -   16  110.00
2  Q125  126.10  126.70  126.10   -   16  126.10
3  Q225  130.15  130.50  130.15   -   21  130.15
4  Q325  125.00  126.85  126.18   -   23  126.18 

New South Wales - BStr
   BStr     Bid     Ask    Last    +/- Vol  Settle
0  FY25  120.29  121.00       -      -   -  120.38
1  CY25  121.00  122.50  122.00      -  14  122.00
2  FY26  120.00  122.00  121.00  -0.19   4  121.19
3  CY26  120.50  121.25  121.50  +0.69   7  120.81
4  FY27  120.25  121.00       -      -   -  120.43 

New South Wales - Caps
   Caps    Bid    Ask   Last    +/- Vol  Settle
0  Q324  10.00  11.00  10.00      -  17   10.00
1  Q424  20.25  21.50  20.50  +0.25  10   20.25
2  Q125  41.00  43.00      -      -   -   41.46
3  Q225  25.50  27.00      -      -   -   26.66
4  Q325  25.00      -      -      -   -   26.54 

New South Wales - CapStr
  CapStr    Bid    Ask   Last    +/- Vol  Settle
0   FY25      -      -      -      -   -   24.49
1   CY25      -      -      -      -   -   28.96
2   FY26  29.40      -      -      -   -   29.40
3   CY26  28.50  30.00  29.00  -0.35   1   29.35
4   FY27  29.00  30.00      -      -   -   29.93 

New South Wales - PQtr
   PQtr     Bid     Ask Last +/- Vol  Settle
0  Q324  116.00  160.00    -   -   -  160.00
1  Q424  125.00  160.00    -   -   -  145.00
2  Q125       -       -    -   -   -  170.73
3  Q225       -       -    -   -   -  150.00
4  Q325       -       -    -   -   -  140.00 

Victoria - PkStr
  PkStr Bid Ask Last +/- Vol  Settle
0  FY25   -   -    -   -   -  156.47
1  CY25   -   -    -   -   -  144.42
2  FY26   -   -    -   -   -  147.97
3  CY26   -   -    -   -   -  160.00
4  FY27   -   -    -   -   -  148.94 

Victoria - BMth
    BMth Bid    Ask Last +/- Vol  Settle
0  Jul24   -      -    -   -   -  142.58
1  Aug24   -      -    -   -   -  108.21
2  Sep24   -  80.00    -   -   -   71.28
3  Oct24   -      -    -   -   -   58.95 

Victoria - BQtr
   BQtr     Bid     Ask    Last    +/-  Vol  Settle
0  Q324  107.75  108.50  107.75      -   18  107.75
1  Q424   58.50   58.95   59.00  +0.05   14   58.95
2  Q125   73.40   74.00   73.50      -   13   73.50
3  Q225   93.00   93.80   93.80      -   10   93.80
4  Q325   88.00   89.25   88.50      -    5   88.50 

Victoria - BStr
   BStr    Bid    Ask   Last    +/- Vol  Settle
0  FY25      -      -      -      -   -   83.53
1  CY25  76.25  76.85  76.65  +0.29   2   76.36
2  FY26  70.00  73.30      -      -   -   72.22
3  CY26  65.50  70.24  69.80  +0.25   8   69.55
4  FY27      -      -      -      -   -   70.17 

Victoria - Caps
   Caps    Bid   Ask   Last    +/- Vol  Settle
0  Q324   6.75   7.5   8.15  +0.65  18     7.5
1  Q424   5.00   7.0      -      -   -     6.3
2  Q125  27.75  29.0  28.00      -  20    28.0
3  Q225   8.25  11.5      -      -   -    10.0
4  Q325  10.50  11.5      -      -   -    10.5 

Victoria - CapStr
  CapStr    Bid    Ask Last +/- Vol  Settle
0   FY25      -      -    -   -   -   12.88
1   CY25  13.00  15.25    -   -   -   14.25
2   FY26  13.85  15.25    -   -   -   14.49
3   CY26  14.50  16.00    -   -   -   14.81
4   FY27  15.40      -    -   -   -   15.42 

Queensland - PQtr
   PQtr     Bid Ask Last +/- Vol  Settle
0  Q324  111.11   -    -   -   -   140.0
1  Q424       -   -    -   -   -    64.5
2  Q125       -   -    -   -   -   103.0
3  Q225       -   -    -   -   -   120.0
4  Q325       -   -    -   -   -   119.0 

Queensland - PkStr
  PkStr Bid Ask Last +/- Vol  Settle
0  FY25   -   -    -   -   -  107.07
1  CY25   -   -    -   -   -  102.24
2  FY26   -   -    -   -   -   77.04
3  CY26   -   -    -   -   -   60.00
4  FY27   -   -    -   -   -   60.00 

Queensland - BMth
    BMth Bid Ask Last +/- Vol  Settle
0  Jul24   -   -    -   -   -  108.07
1  Aug24   -   -    -   -   -   89.86
2  Sep24   -   -    -   -   -   89.86
3  Oct24   -   -    -   -   -   97.00 

Queensland - BQtr
   BQtr     Bid     Ask    Last +/- Vol  Settle
0  Q324   96.00  101.75       -   -   -   96.00
1  Q424   96.75   97.50   97.00   -  12   97.00
2  Q125  133.00  133.50  133.50   -  18  133.50
3  Q225   99.80  100.45   99.80   -  31   99.80
4  Q325   95.00   96.75   96.01   -  15   96.01 

Queensland - BStr
   BStr     Bid     Ask    Last    +/- Vol  Settle
0  FY25  106.50  109.75       -      -   -  106.45
1  CY25  104.00  104.50  104.00  -0.22   7  104.22
2  FY26   99.50  100.00   99.75  -0.12   4   99.87
3  CY26   97.00   98.00   97.40  -0.02   2   97.42
4  FY27       -   94.70   94.50  +0.11   2   94.39 

Queensland - Caps
   Caps    Bid    Ask   Last    +/- Vol  Settle
0  Q324   7.00   9.00   8.25      -  15    8.25
1  Q424  17.25  18.90  19.00  +0.10   1   18.90
2  Q125  42.00  45.25  45.00      -   1   45.00
3  Q225      -  17.00      -      -   -   17.00
4  Q325      -      -      -      -   -   16.84 

South Australia - CapStr
  CapStr    Bid    Ask   Last +/- Vol  Settle
0   FY25      -      -      -   -   -   22.18
1   CY25      -  23.85      -   -   -   23.74
2   FY26      -  23.30      -   -   -   23.19
3   CY26  21.50  23.50  22.99   -  10   22.99
4   FY27      -      -      -   -   -   22.78 

South Australia - PQtr
   PQtr    Bid Ask Last +/- Vol  Settle
0  Q324   95.0   -    -   -   -    95.0
1  Q424  100.0   -    -   -   -   100.0
2  Q125  160.0   -    -   -   -   160.0
3  Q225  100.0   -    -   -   -   100.0
4  Q325   90.0   -    -   -   -    90.0 

South Australia - PkStr
  PkStr Bid Ask Last +/- Vol  Settle
0  FY25   -   -    -   -   -  113.53
1  CY25   -   -    -   -   -  107.21
2  FY26   -   -    -   -   -   69.79
3  CY26   -   -    -   -   -   54.00
4  FY27   -   -    -   -   -   54.00 

South Australia - BMth
    BMth Bid Ask Last +/- Vol  Settle
0  Jul24   -   -    -   -   -  129.78
1  Aug24   -   -    -   -   -  129.78
2  Sep24   -   -    -   -   -  129.78
3  Oct24   -   -    -   -   -   67.32 

South Australia - BQtr
   BQtr     Bid     Ask Last +/- Vol  Settle
0  Q324       -  154.75    -   -   2  129.78
1  Q424       -       -    -   -   2   67.32
2  Q125  108.50  120.00    -   -   2  117.08
3  Q225       -  123.50    -   -   2  116.12
4  Q325       -       -    -   -   -  119.00 

South Australia - BStr
   BStr     Bid     Ask    Last +/- Vol  Settle
0  FY25       -       -  107.50   -   2  107.50
1  CY25       -       -       -   -   -  105.90
2  FY26       -  108.00       -   -   -  104.38
3  CY26       -       -       -   -   -  103.45
4  FY27  100.00  105.00       -   -   -  103.14 

